# How i transfer character from UWP application to android app using bluetooth connection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth, uwp, raspberry-pi

I am developing an application for Raspberry pi its UWP application, so i want to send and receive characters from UWP application  to android app.
SO please tell me what is code for UWP application. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

[This site shows you how to send and receive serial bluetooth data.](http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/707/Win-10-Iot-Core-Bluetooth-Universal-Windows-Serial-App-)

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/djaus2/iotbluetoothserial/tree/master/GenericBluetoothSerialUWApp)